# Proguard - Can't find any super classes

Tags: android, log4j, libraries, proguard

I'm getting this error:

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class       = [org/apache/log4j/chainsaw/Main]
Method      = [<init>()V]
Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [org/apache/log4j/chainsaw/LoadXMLAction] (not even immediate super class [javax/swing/AbstractAction]))
Error: Can't find any super classes of [org/apache/log4j/chainsaw/LoadXMLAction] (not even immediate super class [javax/swing/AbstractAction])
```

Part of my proguard configuration:

```
-dontwarn javax.jms.**
-dontwarn com.sun.jdmk.comm.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.**
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.**
-dontwarn com.sun.**
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**

-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\acra-4.5.0.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\activation.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\additionnal.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\android-support-v4.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\annotations.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\google-api-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\jtar-1.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\log4j-1.2.15.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\mail.jar'
-libraryjars 'D:\Workspace\android\libs\simple-xml-2.6.9.jar'
```

The library for log4j is there, so what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

As I have found the problem is raised during optimalization.
Shrink and obfuscation is working.

Comment: Which jar are you using? I have the same problem in one of my projects (but not in another one strangely enough), I use the jar `log4j-android-1.2.17-1.jar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who need a fast solution on using Log4J on Android, Krivers' update actually served as a hint: setting `-dontoptimize` in ProGuard configuration turns off optimization and thus avoids the error (although this should only be considered as a workaround).

In fact, the Android Tools Project Site had also [suggested to turn off ProGuard optimization](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements):

> Dalvik performs many of its own optimizations, and some of the optimizations performed by ProGuard are incompatible with Dalvik, so to avoid hard-to-figure-out bugs (and because the net performance gain is usually small), the default configuration turns off optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The class org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.LoadXMLAction extends the class javax.swing.AbstractAction. This latter class is part of Swing, which is not present in Android. Therefore, LoadXMLAction can never be used in practice. Furthermore, ProGuard can't analyze this class properly without its complete class hierarchy.

Solution: you should avoid adding LoadXMLAction to your application libraries, either by not putting the corresponding Apache jar in your libs directory, or by filtering out the class (and similar classes) from the ProGuard `injars` options (more difficult in the standard build process), or by removing the class from the jar.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and have no idea why Proguard needs the LoadXMLAction in the first place. Any more details of how to filter out the class? The jar is `log4j-android-1.2.17-1.jar`